# Webkit transform rotate on hover pseudo not working in safari

Tags: css

I have a list item with a pseudo border set for each one, my hover effect works in google chrome but fails in in safari, they both use the same rendering engine so why is it not working?

```
.page-content ol li:before {
      background: #338ec9;
      background: url(../images/tie.png) no-repeat 0;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      padding-left: 35px;
      font-size: 1.2em;

  position: absolute;    
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;

  height: 25px;
  width: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;

  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;

  border-radius: 2em;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 0.6s;     
}

.page-content ol li:hover:before {        
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

Comment: I have read that setting display block on the li should fix this but it makes no difference.

Comment: usually a pseudo element needs a *content* to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

add

```
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
```

to

```
.page-content ol li:before
```

it should do the trick standing to: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp